# Web-scraping with selenium using google translate

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping, google-translate

**I am trying to scrape multiple web pages across the world. So, I want to translate the website using Google translate extension and then scrape the page using selenium.**

I did some research and figured out how to add extension while running selenium.

1) [download google translate extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en)

2) [Create .crx file](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-create-crx-file-from-already.html)

3) [add extension to selenium](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-add-extension-to-google-chrome.html)

but I have no idea how to automatically execute the extension (By default, it does nothing)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_extension('./translate.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "./chromedriver", chrome_options = option)
driver.get("naver.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))

''' @@@@ Here I want something like@@@@
driver.execute_extension("translate this page")
'''

print driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text
driver.quit()
```

Also, I found that the extension doesn't translate the original HTML, so I might have to use a different method for crawling. (Maybe passing ctrl-a, ctrl-c, ctrl-v instead by_tag_name("body"))

Could you give me any pointer for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> driver.execute_extension

Seems to me if you can open the extension by Selenium (see [an example in C#](https://www.edureka.co/community/48395/there-load-extension-chrome-browser-using-selenium-webdriver?show=48397#a48397)). Then you by Selenium may click on the **TRANSLATE THIS PAGE** link:

[image]

### Shortcut

Use [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/apis).